# How to reference loss score in LearningRateScheduler

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have a working Step_Decay:

```
def step_decay(epoch):
    initial_lr = 0.01
    decay_factor=0.1
    step_size=1
    new_lr = initial_lr * (decay_factor ** np.floor(epoch / step_size))
    print("Learning rate: " + str(new_lr))
    return new_lr

lr_sched = keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)
```

But I want to stop reducing the learning rate once loss < 0.1.

How can I access epoch loss number to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

By keras.callbacks.Callback to record loss history and learning rate during the training procedure.

[learning-rate-schedules - Access to loss by step_decay with history loss](https://towardsdatascience.com/learning-rate-schedules-and-adaptive-learning-rate-methods-for-deep-learning-2c8f433990d1)

```
   def step_decay(epoch):
   initial_lrate = 0.1
   drop = 0.5
   epochs_drop = 10.0
   lrate = initial_lrate * math.pow(drop,  
           math.floor((1+epoch)/epochs_drop))
   return lrate
lrate = LearningRateScheduler(step_decay) 




class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
   self.losses = []
   self.lr = []

def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
   self.losses.append(logs.get(‘loss’))
   self.lr.append(step_decay(len(self.losses)))

loss_history = LossHistory()
lrate = LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)
callbacks_list = [loss_history, lrate]
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
   validation_data=(X_test, y_test), 
   epochs=epochs, 
   batch_size=batch_size, 
   callbacks=callbacks_list, 
   verbose=2)
```

Access epoch loss number:

```
def get_learningrate_metric(optimizer):
    def learningrate(y_true, y_pred):
        return optimizer.learningrate
    return learningrate

x = Input((50,))
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(x, out)

optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)
learningrate_metric = get_learningrate_metric(optimizer)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['acc', learningrate_metric])

# reducing the learning rate by half every 2 epochs
cbks = [LearningRateScheduler(lambda epoch: 0.001 * 0.5 ** (epoch // 2)),
        TensorBoard(write_graph=False)]
X = np.random.rand(1000, 50)
Y = np.random.randint(2, size=1000)
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=10, callbacks=cbks)
```

or

```
Adadelta = optimizers.Adadelta(lr=1.0, rho=0.95, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.1)
```

> Adadelta is an extension of Adagrad that seeks to reduce its aggressive, monotonically decreasing learning rate.

[get the learning rate value after every epoch](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7874)
Or can it help you?

[EarlyStopping](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping)

Comment: Sorry - how does that give me access to loss with step_decay()?

Comment: @ManInMoon By keras.callbacks.Callback to record loss history and learning rate during the training procedure. I updated my answer and please look at the link I sent.

Comment: Wow - that seems very complicated!